# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: like model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am getting django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: feed_like.user_id
on my model . How can i solve it

**my models.py**

class Like(models.Model):

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(HNUsers, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
liked = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Likes"
```

**my views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
@parser_classes([FormParser, MultiPartParser])
def like_post_api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        print(data)
        serializer = PostLikeSerializer(data=request.data)
        print("print ", serializer)
        post = Posts.objects.get(id=data['post'])
        print(post)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**my serializer.py**

```
class PostLikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = CommentUserSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'post',

        )
```

Comment: Could you show the full error message with traceback? Also please fix the formatting of the first snippet.

Comment: Have you tried removing read_only=True when you set the user serializer?

Comment: yes, I tried but if I remove read_only=True , I dont get the user info associated with that

Comment: can you add the POSTed data ?

Comment: yes , I can post the data

Answer (score 1):

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(HNUsers, related_name='likes', null= True, blank=True on_delete=models.CASCADE)
# your other fields
```

set your `user` field's `null` attribute to `True`. This will remove NOT NULL constraint failed error. Also run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` command to your cmd.